# Views in Dialog disappear after Keyboard is opened and closed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I have a `Dialog` that looks like this

[image: Dialog before keyboard appears]

When keyboard appears, it looks like this. Nothing out of the ordinary.

[image: Dialog when keyboard appears]

But when the keyboard is closed, the button at the bottom of my dialog disappears and never comes back.

[image]

I have never seen this happen before. Any help would be appreciated.